# Laravel, How to Find Uploaded Files by Specific Pattern in The Files' Name?

Tags: php, laravel, download, upload

first of all to explain what I mean by my question, when I upload my files to the local storage I save them the following way:

```
$files = $request->file('files');

        if ($request->hasFile('files')) {
            foreach ($files as $file) {
                //Get filename with the extension
                $fileNameWithExt = $file->getClientOriginalName();
                //Filename to store example: lead_4_document.pdf
                $fileNameToStore =  'lead_' . $lead->id . '_' . $fileNameWithExt;
                //Upload image
                $path = $file->storeAs('/user_uploads', $fileNameToStore);

                $lead->uploadFile()->create(array('filename' => $fileNameToStore, 'file_url' => $path, 'lead_id' => $lead->id));
            }
        }
```

So essentially I prepend lead_ the lead id and another _ to whatever the file is originally called during upload. The problem I face now is that I need to retrieve the associated files according to my lead ids. Here is my attempt so far:

```
$searchParam = 'lead_'.$lead->id.'_';
//$fileNames = File::glob('storage/user_uploads/'.$searchParam.'*');
//$files = File::get($fileNames);
$allFiles = Storage::files('user_uploads');
dd($allFiles);
```

Just to clarify, the 'File::glob' way seems to work, though it only outputs the names of the files not the actual files as object, which is what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I took a step back and went about this whole associated uploaded file to lead relationship a different way. Here is how I did it, just in case anyone stumbles across this and find themselves in the same boat as me.
The file upload now does a couple of things:

```
//check if file(s) is present in the request
        if ($request->hasFile('files')) {
            //checks if a directory already exists for a given lead (by id)
            if (Storage::exists('/leads/'.$request->lead_id)) {
                //if yes set the directory path to the existing folder
                $directory = '/leads/'.$request->lead_id;
            }
            else {
                //if not create a new directory with the lead id
                Storage::makeDirectory('/leads/'.$request->lead_id);
                $directory = '/leads/'.$request->lead_id;
            }

            foreach ($files as $file) {
                //Get filename with the extension
                $fileNameWithExt = $file->getClientOriginalName();
                //Filename to store example: lead_4_document.pdf
                $fileNameToStore =  'lead_' . $lead->id . '_' . $fileNameWithExt;
                //Upload image
                //'/user_uploads'
                $file->storeAs($directory, $fileNameToStore);

                //$lead->uploadFile()->create(array('filename' => $fileNameToStore, 'file_url' => $path, 'lead_id' => $lead->id));
            }
        }
```

So essentially, instead of trying to put all files into a single folder then checking the individual files for the 'lead_##' prepend, I instead create a folder with the id of the lead, this I then use the following way in my view function:

```
 $directory = '/leads/'.$lead->id;

        if (Storage::exists($directory)) {
            $files = File::files('storage/'.$directory);
        }
        else {
            $files = '';
        }
```

Simply checking if the directory exists with the given lead ID, then if there are files uploaded either assign it the content, or set it blank (this is used for displaying an 'attachments' section on my page if not empty).